# Finding value +1 within a group

Tags: r, filter, dplyr, group-by, any

I have a large dataframe that I have grouped by `Date`. Within each date group, I'd like to keep the rows for rooms that are next door to one another, i.e. `Room.num` = any `Room.num` in group +/- 1

```
 Date        Room.num  
1 2019.08.21  1  
2 2019.08.21  2  
3 2020.07.18  6  
4 2020.07.18  1  
5 2020.07.18  3
```

I want to end up with just

```
  Date        Room.num  
1 2019.08.21  1  
2 2019.08.21  2
```

1. I have tried

```
df %>% 
   group_by(Date)
   filter(Room.num=1)
```

which gives me

Date        Room.num
1 2019.08.21  1
4 2020.07.18  1

2. I have also tried

```
df %>% 
   group_by(Date)
   filter(any(Room.num=1))
```

This gives me

```
  Date        Room.num  
1 2019.08.21  1  
2 2019.08.21  2  
3 2020.07.18  6  
4 2020.07.18  1  
5 2020.07.18  3
```

i.e. any group with a `Room.num=1`

3. But I am not able to do what I want keep rows whichhave a room number that is +/- 1 of any other `Room.num` in that `Date` group

```
df %>% 
   group_by(Date)
   filter(Room.num==any(Room.num)+1)
```

I get

```
Date        Room.num  
2 2019.08.21  2
```

The second `Room.num` is always = 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can do this in `tidyverse`

```r
df <- read.table(header = T, text = 'Date Room.num
1 2019.08.21 1
2 2019.08.21 2
3 2020.07.18 6
4 2020.07.18 1
5 2020.07.18 3
')

library(tidyverse)
df  %>%
  group_by(Date) %>%
  filter(map_lgl(Room.num, ~ .x %in% c(Room.num -1, Room.num +1))) %>%
  ungroup()
#> # A tibble: 2 x 2
#>   Date       Room.num
#>   <chr>         <int>
#> 1 2019.08.21        1
#> 2 2019.08.21        2
```

---

If you, however, want to avoid `purrr::map_lgl` use this similar baseR function like this

```
df  %>%
  group_by(Date) %>%
  filter(unlist(Map(\(.x) .x %in% c(Room.num -1, Room.num +1), Room.num))) %>%
  ungroup()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution:

```
#Just creating your dataset
df <- data.frame(Date = c(as.Date('2019-08-21'), as.Date('2019-08-21'),
                          as.Date('2020-07-18'), as.Date('2020-07-18'),
                          as.Date('2020-07-18')),
                 Room.num = c(1,2,6,1,3))

df %>% 
  group_by(Date) %>%
  filter(any(abs(diff(Room.num)) == 1))
```